# How to add a if condition in a function in a table cell in yii?

Tags: php, yii

Hi guys iam tring to add an if condition that will show either one button or the other, i have tried everything i could think of. Iam using gridview in Yii. Can someone help me add an if condition inside the function under value to this :

```
         array(
                'header' => '',
                'type' => 'raw',
                 'value' => function($data) {
                          return '<div class="booking_buttons">' .
                          '<a href="' . Yii::app()->createUrl("toursextra/viewrequest/" . $data->tourextra_id) . '" class="btn_1 outline">' . __("Booking") . '</a>
                           <a href="' . Yii::app()->createUrl("book/view/" . $data->private_confirm) . '" class="btn_3">Details</a>
                                 </div>';
                                             },
               ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you are looking for somethings like this

```
array(
    'header' => '',
    'type' => 'raw',
     'value' => function($data) {
              if ( $yourDataTest == true ){
                return '<div class="booking_buttons">' .
                    '<a href="' . Yii::app()->createUrl("toursextra/viewrequest/" . $data->tourextra_id) . '" class="btn_1 outline">' . __("Booking") . '</a></div>' ;
              } else {
              return '<div class="booking_buttons">' .
                '<a href="' . Yii::app()->createUrl("book/view/" . $data->private_confirm) . '" class="btn_3">Details</a></div>';
              }
          },
),
```

Comment: there is a sytax error , i cant get it working , u have any ideas

Comment: I have update the answer ...

Comment: you are awesome , thanxs for the help !